# MPI block other ranks to execute until rank 0's task is finished

Tags: python, c++, c, parallel-processing, mpi

I am new in MPI, Here is the code structure I am implementing right now:

```
import time

def A():
   //some simple codes here to execute. Lets say
   print('Hello World from A')
   time.sleep(5)

def B():
    //some simple codes here to execute.Lets say
    print('Hello World from B')
    time.sleep(5)

def C():
    print('Hello World from C')
    print('>>>>>>>>>>>>> The place where I will start to make parallelization')
    scores = []
    for i in range (1, 1000):
       score = score_calculator(i) // ignore this function
       scores.append(score)
    print('<<<<<<<<<<<<< The place where I will stop to make parallelization')
```

for example this is in `hello_world.py`

I will call `mpiexec -n 4 hello_world.py`

So my point is - there will be 4 ranks here. the function A and B are sequential, so no need of other ranks there. My parallelization will be here in C function.

What I want to do

A and B will run sequentially. so I will call `if rank == 0` in each of the function.

after `print('Hello World from C')` all other ranks will be forced to wait, until the rank = 0 is finished.

When Rank 0 is finished, then I configure the next parts for parallelization.

My Question is:

So how I can make wait other ranks to finish the rank 0?

Any of implementation in python or C is welcomed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if (0 == rank) {// sequential part};MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);`

Comment: "so no need of other ranks there" MPI doesn't work that way. All "ranks" execute the same code. You can put a conditional in front of bits but all processes ( <= that's the better term) execute everything. "The place where I will start to make parallelization" Nope. Doesn't work that way.